# Better way to swap the components in Angular 6

Tags: angular

In my Angular 6 app I've code something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="someSettings === 'abc'">

      <abc-container [prop1]="" [prop2]="" (ev1)="" (ev2)="">
      </abc-container>

      <xyz-container [prop1]="" [prop2]="" (ev1)="" (ev2)="">
      </xyz-container>

</div>
```

Now based on someSettings I want to swap these two components and therefore I would use another block of code e.g.:

```
<div *ngIf="someSettings === 'xyz'">

      <xyz-container [prop1]="" [prop2]="" (ev1)="" (ev2)="">
      </xyz-container>

      <abc-container [prop1]="" [prop2]="" (ev1)="" (ev2)="">
      </abc-container>

</div>
```

but this is duplication e.g. If I've added or removed some property or event I've to change it at both locations, is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can optimize a bit using *ngIf, ng-template.

```
<div *ngIf="someSettings === 'abc'">
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="abc"></ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="xyz"></ng-container>
</div>
<div *ngIf="someSettings === 'xyz'">
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="xyz"></ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="abc"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #xyz>
  <xyz-container [prop1]="" [prop2]="" (ev1)="" (ev2)="">
  </xyz-container>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #abc>
  <abc-container [prop1]="" [prop2]="" (ev1)="" (ev2)="">
  </abc-container>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I'm looking for because the previous implementation was violating the DRY principle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `NgClass` and `display: flex` with `flex-direction: column/column-reverse` to swap between the components

Comment: Thanks for comments guys, I edited the answer, hope it's clear now!